# How to map common entity

Tags: orm, jpa, mapping

I'm wondering if it is all possible to nicely map common entities with JPA.

What is a common entity for me? Say many of my domain entities have (an) associated image(s). So, there'd be relationships like `UserProfile -> Image` (profile picture) or `Event ->* Image` (images promoting an event, one-to-many).

With pure SQL I could have an `image` table with an `owner_id` column holding `UserProfile#ID` or `Event#ID`. Since I'll never have to find the owner of an image but the image(s) to an owner instead, I don't care that I can't instantly tell whether image 5 is a profile picture or an event image.

I guess on JPA-level the same "hack" could work as long as I don't have one-to-many or many-to-one relationships to `Image` because they'd need a back reference to... yes, that's the problem. I can't create that back reference.

The only feasible approach that comes to mind is to create an `abstract Image` holding all common `Image` fields and then to create a concrete sub-class for each relationship. Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand how you "pure SQL" approach would work: if you want to get an images for `Event` #5 you would also get images for `UserProfile` #5, right?.

Another approach to model this is to introduce a join table.

You can create normal join tables for each type of image owner with foreign keys to the owner and to the image in it:

```
@Entity
public class UserProfile {
    @OneToOne @JoinTable
    private Image image;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Event {
    @OneToMany // Unidirectional one-to-many uses join table by default
    private List<Image> image;
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can create a single additional table containing primary key only:

```
@Entity
public class Images {
    @OneToMany @JoinColumn
    private List<Image> images;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class UserProfile {
    @OneToOne
    private Images images;
    ...
}
```

Comment: "I don't quite understand how you "pure SQL" approach would work: if you want to get an images for Event #5 you would also get images for UserProfile #5, right?."

Ah, right, forgot to mention that we use IDs that are unique system-wide.

Comment: For the `UserProfile -> Image` case I ended up using an inverse 1-to-1 relationship (i.e. image id stored as foreign key in `user_profile` table).